# Is there any way to show delete button on Swipe left and Right on tableview call like iOS 6 in iOS 7.

Tags: ios

I am showing delete button on the UITableView cell on Swipe left and right.

It is working fine on iOS 6. But on iOS 7 instead of swipe delete tableview cell scroll to left and a delete button appears on the right most.

Is there any way to show delete button by Swipe left and Right on tableviewcell like iOS 6 in iOS 7 as I don't want iOS 7 default delete behavior.

Comment: That's the new delete delete cell button, so if you really want to have the old one, you will have to write your own code for that (using touch events). That is going to be tricky. Why don't you want this? To me it's the same thing, except the design, which looks like iOS 7.

Comment: My client is not happy with the new UI, so want to customize it.

Comment: Well, then charge him for 1/2 days to code this. You will need to code it yourself. I would tell him something like: it's not the "new way of doing things", it's possible to do it, but it will take time, it's not going to be consistent with iOS 7, and it's likely to create some bugs in the future.

Comment: Yes, I am also feeling there are few bugs waiting for me once I implement this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3 Try

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {

    return true
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        objects.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    } 
}
```